# How to configure Eclipse for Python in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, pydev

I am not getting Window > Preferences > PyDev > option in eclipse.I tried from eclipse marketplace but am facing some issues. What is the process for the same?

Comment: Google is your friend on this one...

Comment: You should elaborate more on what you tried and versions/OS of everything you are using.

Comment: Please define the phrase "facing some issues".

Comment: I am using Eclipse on ubuntu 12.04. I tried to configure Python in eclipse using Eclipse Marketplace, but getting error while installing. Below is the error, "An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2250249456466075300.jar "

Answer (score 3):

I would say read this - http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html. This should answer most of your questions. If you are a bit more flexible on not using eclipse id say use PyCharm http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/.

Comment: I did same as mentioned in http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html, but got below error during installation at 47%. Error = "An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.3.3.201401272249.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8983472687111646539.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8983472687111646539.jar". What should I do in this case??

Comment: I dont know - havent seen this error - could also try this Try http://techcolleague.com/2011/02/install-eclipse-and-pydev-on-ubuntu/ -at this point - you should really try using google a bit more - think of Google as your friend who "almost always" has the answers to your questions.

Comment: Also try uninstalling eclipse then re-installing - then try any of the above again.